# How to make AWS CodeCommit repo accessible to Cognito UserPool Users?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, gitea

Trying to make AWS CodeCommit accessible to Cognito UserPool users [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/temporary-access.html):

1. Created an *IAM Role* with `AWSCodeCommitPowerUser`,
2. Set up its trust relationships with the *User Pool*,
3. Installed `git-remote-codecommit` and [configured the profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/temporary-access.html#temporary-access-configure-credentials).
4. Next, trying any of the following:

- Set `source_profile = default`, where the `default` credentials profile contains an IAM user (wrong way but just to check).
  Executing `git clone codecommit://CodeAccessProfile@repo` throws:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/name.surname is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource...`

- Login as a Cognito User Pool user in the web app,
  get the *Cognito IdToken* from the response,
  and using it invoke [assume-role-with-web-identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role-with-web-identity.html). Getting:

`An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Provided Token is not a Login With Amazon token`

I might need to set up `web_identity_token_file=token-file.txt` in the profile, but where to get the token associated with the Cognito User?

I'd like to know how to make git-remote-codecommit work for Cognito UserPool Users avoiding such pain with STS tokens, just properly configuring the profile?

UPD:
Debriefing

Having spent a few weeks on AWS-based POC, we decided to implement all the pipelines on lightweight and fully controllable services run in k8 such as [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding my two cents: I'm facing exactly your use case but even if I might have done some progress I'm still not able to clone a repo with a Cognito User.

To get the `token-file.txt` I use the following command:

```
    aws cognito-idp initiate-auth \
    --region eu-central-1 \
    --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH \
    --client-id 1234abcd1234abcd1234abcd \
    --auth-parameters USERNAME=<username>,PASSWORD=<password> | \
    jq .AuthenticationResult.IdToken | \
    sed 's/"//g' > token-file.txt
```

following the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782519/aws-cli-how-to-generate-security-tokens-for-a-cognito-user) answer.

My `.aws/credentials` file looks like this:

```
    role_arn=arn:aws:iam::1234567890123:role/Cognito_TESTAuth_Role
    web_identity_token_file=<path-to-token-file.txt>
```

Where `Cognito_TESTAuth_Role` is the IAM role that was added by AWS when I created the Identity Pool linked to the Cognito User Pool.
I added the AWSCodeCommitPowerUser policy and a policy to allow all `sts` actions to this role:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
               "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": "sts:*",
               "Resource": "*"
            }
       ]
    }
```

but when I try to clone the repo I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

Which is different from yours: while looks like I got a valid token (which is encouraging) it looks like I am still missing something else.

I wonder if you made any progress with this issue and if getting the token as described above allows you to access CodeCommit.